# yum install python-setuptools to install easy_install and ansible - errors: AttributeError: other Python Errors

Tags: python, pip, ansible, yum, easy-install

Goal: Install ansible on a RedHat Linux machine.

**Little overview on how it all started:**
When my Linux machine was RedHat 5.9 (Tikanga), the default python installed version was 2.4. I tried my best, but couldn't get anything to work as Ansible requires python >= 2.6. I tried installing 2.7.9 on Linux 5.9 version but then things started to act up really fast.

I did try 2.7.9 python on Linux 5.9 as "make altinstall" instead of install but still there were lots of errors while running yum / etc system level commands.

Few errors which came there were (with or without running sudo):

**# sudo pip install ansible**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 236, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2097, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1830, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 211
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or

**# sudo easy_install pip**

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 6.0.8
Processing pip-6.0.8-py2.4.egg
pip 6.0.8 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2.4 script to /usr/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
```

or

**# sudo pip install ansible**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 236, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2097, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1830, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 211
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or

**# sudo easy_install ansible**

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in ?
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

etc....

Finally to my luck, I thought, let's try installing python again from scratch (so I ran **yum erase python**, !!! beware !!!!) and to my knowledge, it was the best command I ever ran in my experience with a little oversight. End result: I ended up creating a new product, here: http://www.keepcalmandcarryon.com/creator/?shortcode=qCsMlpyc

**Anyways**, ... Now, I got the server revived with a newer version of RedHat (version 6.6 Santiago) and this time default Python on it was: 2.6.6.

**Current situation: THIS is what I'm facing now, on RH Linux 5.9 with Python 2.6.6 installed.**

I'm running: **sudo easy_install pip** but I got an error:

```
sudo: easy_install: command not found
```

To resolve the above, I'm now running: `sudo yum install python-setuptools`
It found it... but showing me some an error.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
http://74.125.194.100/yum/x86_64/6Server/%24YUM0/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://74.125.194.100/yum/x86_64/supplemental/%24YUM0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.6.10-3.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                   Arch                                           Version                                                Repository                                              Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python-setuptools                                         noarch                                         0.6.10-3.el6                                           release.update                                         336 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 336 k
Installed size: 1.5 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
http://74.125.194.100/yum/x86_64/6Server/%24YUM0/Server/../Packages/python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.


Error Downloading Packages:
  python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch: failure: ../Packages/python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch.rpm from release.update: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

-bash-4.1$
```

Any idea, how can i get easy_install, pip or ansible on my Linux machine 6.6 (now).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran the following commands to fix everything and now ansible is finally installed:

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

But at this stage, I got an error for Jinja2 ... as below: **ImportError: No module named setuptools**

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
ImportError: No module named setuptools
-bash-4.1$
```

To fix the above and proceed, I ran the following commands to get python-setuptools (which installs easy_install)

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

Great, now I have easy_install installed on my machine.

```
-bash-4.1$ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
-bash-4.1$
```

At this point, I wanted to install ANSIBLE, so I ran the following:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install ansible
```

The last line in the above ansible install command's output was:

```
Successfully installed ansible-1.9.0.1 jinja2-2.7.3 markupsafe-0.23 pycrypto-2.6.1
```

Now, I can see ansible on my machine.

```
-bash-4.1$ which ansible
/usr/bin/ansible
-bash-4.1$
```

Oh, oh... something is still not good:

**-bash-4.1$ ansible --help**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 36, in <module>
    from ansible.runner import Runner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import atfork
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    import FortunaGenerator
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util.number import ceil_shift, exact_log2, exact_div
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 56, in <module>
    if _fastmath is not None and not _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'
```

**-bash-4.1$**

I checked, my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable was already set/exported as:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/lib64
```

Then what else... OK.

Ran the following steps/commands to resolve the above error and get ansible to actually WORK!!!. For prompts, I said Yes "y".

---

```
echo "y" | sudo pip uninstall pycrypto
echo "y" | sudo yum erase python-crypto
echo "y" | sudo pip uninstall ansible
sudo pip install ansible
## Time to get gmplib 6.0.0(a) etc
wget https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.0.0a.tar.bz2
tar -xvjpf gmp-6.0.0a.tar.bz2
## Change to the above extracted folder and run some commands, seems like they'll run forever.
cd gmp-6.0.0
./configure
sudo make  || echo "these few steps will take good amt of time to complete"
sudo make check || echo "hang on and see if all tests passes in the check process"
sudo make install || echo "final shenzi will be done shortly"
sudo make check || echo "really!!!! ????"
which ansible
ansible || ansible --help
```

**!!! FINALLY !!!** ----

**-bash-4.1$ which ansible**

```
/usr/bin/ansible
```

**-bash-4.1$ ansible**

```
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]

Options:
  -a MODULE_ARGS, --args=MODULE_ARGS
                        module arguments
  --ask-become-pass     ask for privilege escalation password
  -k, --ask-pass        ask for SSH password
  --ask-su-pass         ask for su password (deprecated, use become)
  -K, --ask-sudo-pass   ask for sudo password (deprecated, use become)
  --ask-vault-pass      ask for vault password
  -B SECONDS, --background=SECONDS
                        run asynchronously, failing after X seconds
                        (default=N/A)
  -b, --become          run operations with become (nopasswd implied)
  --become-method=BECOME_METHOD
                        privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo),
                        valid choices: [ sudo | su | pbrun | pfexec | runas ]
  --become-user=BECOME_USER
                        run operations as this user (default=root)
  -C, --check           don't make any changes; instead, try to predict some
                        of the changes that may occur
  -c CONNECTION, --connection=CONNECTION
                        connection type to use (default=smart)
  -e EXTRA_VARS, --extra-vars=EXTRA_VARS
                        set additional variables as key=value or YAML/JSON
  -f FORKS, --forks=FORKS
                        specify number of parallel processes to use
                        (default=5)
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host file
                        (default=/etc/ansible/hosts)
  -l SUBSET, --limit=SUBSET
                        further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern
  --list-hosts          outputs a list of matching hosts; does not execute
                        anything else
  -m MODULE_NAME, --module-name=MODULE_NAME
                        module name to execute (default=command)
  -M MODULE_PATH, --module-path=MODULE_PATH
                        specify path(s) to module library (default=None)
  -o, --one-line        condense output
  -P POLL_INTERVAL, --poll=POLL_INTERVAL
                        set the poll interval if using -B (default=15)
  --private-key=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
                        use this file to authenticate the connection
  -S, --su              run operations with su (deprecated, use become)
  -R SU_USER, --su-user=SU_USER
                        run operations with su as this user (default=root)
                        (deprecated, use become)
  -s, --sudo            run operations with sudo (nopasswd) (deprecated, use
                        become)
  -U SUDO_USER, --sudo-user=SUDO_USER
                        desired sudo user (default=root) (deprecated, use
                        become)
  -T TIMEOUT, --timeout=TIMEOUT
                        override the SSH timeout in seconds (default=10)
  -t TREE, --tree=TREE  log output to this directory
  -u REMOTE_USER, --user=REMOTE_USER
                        connect as this user (default=c400093)
  --vault-password-file=VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE
                        vault password file
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable
                        connection debugging)
  --version             show program's version number and exit
```

**-bash-4.1$**

PS: Stay away if you can from "*yum erase python*" and entering "y" for it, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the errors shows in OP are due to the version mismatch. E.g. `except: XXX as obj` syntax was [introduced in 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes).

I expect situation compounded because you had both 2.4 and 2.6 installed and then you used `sudo` to install stuff.

It's much better to open an interactive shell as root, set PATH and PYTHONPATH properly before installing so many python modules via `yum` or `pip`, so you know which modules are installed to which prefix.

`yum erase python` is stupidity as you probably learned the hard way.

all these are yum configuration errors:

```
http://74.125.194.100/yum/x86_64/6Server/%24YUM0/Server/../Packages/python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.

Error Downloading Packages:
  python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch: failure: ../Packages/python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch.rpm from release.update: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

All in all [ansible installation instructions](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html) are pretty reliable.

---

--edit--

> The only thing is even when PATH was set to use 2.7.9 python (for
>   which python), and PYTHONPATH / PYTHONHOME were set, Linux 5.9 version
>   was still picking python version 2.4 site packages and the utilities
>   in Linux 5.9 are tightly dependent upon python 2.4. Under /usr/xxx
>   there no folders for LIB for python 2.7.9 at that time until I
>   switched the whole Linux to 6.6 version. And instead of using "make
>   install" for manually installing python, I used "make altinstall" so
>   that both can sit side by side. –  Arun Sangal

On RHEL 5.x: `/usr/bin/python` would remain 2.4 even when you install 2.6+ (which would goto `/usr/bin/python2.6` or `/usr/bin/python26` or something like that. So the default python is still 2.4 (even after installing 2.6+)

On RHEL 6.x: python 2.4 is not installed by default. So `/usr/bin/python` would be 2.6 by default. So the default python is 2.6.

Most of the utilities/scripts would be executed with `/usr/bin/python` hence *you feel like* 'utilities in Linux 5.9 are tightly dependent upon python 2.4'.

Usually the problem is scripts written for 2.6+ get executed with `/usr/bin/python` on RHEL 5.x, viz python 2.4. "*AFAIK*" other-way-round (running 2.4 scripts with 2.6 interpreter) is a lot more compatible (not fully).

Comment: I agree and accepted this as an answer. The only thing is even when PATH was set to use 2.7.9 python (for `which python`), and PYTHONPATH / PYTHONHOME were set, Linux 5.9 version was still picking python version 2.4 site packages and the utilities in Linux 5.9 are tightly dependent upon python 2.4. Under /usr/xxx there're no folders for LIB for python 2.7.9 at that time until I switched the whole Linux to 6.6 version. And instead of using "make install" for manually installing python 2.7.9 on RH Linux 5.9, I used "make altinstall" so that both can sit side by side.